# Fit table inside modal element Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, react-bootstrap

I have modal styled with `.modal .modal-dialog { width: 80%; }`, and I'm trying to fit table-responsive table to fill modal body vertically. Table has only one column, that means it has to change row height in this case I guess (table with responsive row height). Modal created with React-Bootstrap.

Update modal code:

```
var ModalView = React.createClass({


getInitialState: function(){
    return { showModal: false, tableView: false, image: [] };
  },

  loadDataFromServer: function() {
    $.getJSON(this.props.url,{id: this.props.id},
      function(data) {
        this.setState({image: data});
      }.bind(this)
    );
  },

  close: function(){
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  },

  open: function(){
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
    this.loadDataFromServer();
  },

  showGrid: function(){
    this.setState({ tableView: true });
  },

  showImage: function(){
    this.setState({ tableView: false });
  },

  render: function() {
    const Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
    const Modal = ReactBootstrap.Modal;
    var base64string = this.state.image;
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.open}>
          Show
        </Button>

        <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>{this.props.heading}</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            {this.state.tableView
              ? <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-8"></div>
                <div className="col-md-3"><Button onClick={this.showImage}>Show Image</Button></div>
                </div>

              : <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-8">
                  <div className="col-md-2">
                    <div className="table-responsive">
                      <table className="table">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th className="text-center vert-align">Antigen</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td className="text-center vert-align">1</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td className="text-center vert-align">2</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td className="text-center vert-align">3</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td className="text-center vert-align">4</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td className="text-center vert-align">5</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td className="text-center vert-align">6</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td className="text-center vert-align">7</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td className="text-center vert-align">8</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-5">
                    <img className="img-responsive" src={"data:image/jpg;base64," + base64} />
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-2">
                    <div className="table-responsive">
                      <table className="table">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th className="text-center vert-align">Antigen</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td className="text-center vert-align">1</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td className="text-center vert-align">2</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td className="text-center vert-align">3</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td className="text-center vert-align">4</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td className="text-center vert-align">5</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td className="text-center vert-align">6</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td className="text-center vert-align">7</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td className="text-center vert-align">8</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <div className="col-md-3"><Button onClick={this.showGrid}>Show Grid</Button></div>
                </div>
            }

          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Please provide some code on which we can work on or see your progress and where you may have went wrong. I looked at the examples given at react bootstrap homepage and their modals height depends on its content. So without any insight in your actual code there is nothing I can do for you...

Comment: @Seika85 thanks for your reply, I added code to my question. Please note that my image is bigger than table and what Im trying to achivieve is to strech table vertically as it contains labels for the image.